# Python: LookupError: unknown encoding: cp0

Tags: python, encoding, nltk, spyder, miniconda

I am trying to execute a simple nltk code: `nltk.sent_tokenize(text)` and am getting error `LookupError: unknown encoding: cp0`. I tried typing in `chcp` in my IPython Console and I am getting the same error.

I am working on Windows10 desktop, executing Python code over Miniconda > Spyder IDE. I have Python 2.7 installed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this issue, but had to uninstall Miniconda and Python. I reinstalled Anaconda, launched Spyder from Anaconda-Navigator and its all working fine now. But I still don't understand the cause of this issue. It will be great if someone is able to explain.